# Angular4 Fetch data before navigating Route Resolve

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5, angular4-router

I am trying to use the Angular Route Resolve to fetch component data before the route is activated.

All the examples I have seen call one method in the service and return, I have 5 different methods in the service which need to be called b4 the component is activated.

Below is example of what I am trying to achieve, the ContactService has 3 methods that all need to be called - how can I return all 3 methods in one call?

Any pointers appreciated.

Contact-Resolver.ts - below

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { ContactsService } from './contacts.service';

@Injectable()
export class ContactResolve implements Resolve<Contact>
{

  constructor(private contactsService: ContactsService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot)
  {
    return this.contactsService.getContact(route.paramMap.get('id')); //method in Service
  }

//  return this.contactsService.getCities(); //Another method in Service that also needs to be called

 // return this.contactsService.getAllParts(); //Another method in Service that also needs to be called


}
```

Comment: What do the methods return? Observables?

Comment: @martin Yes they return Observables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use just `forkJoin` that will wait until all source Observable complete:

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
  return Observable.forkJoin(
    this.contactsService.getContact(route.paramMap.get('id')),
    this.contactsService.getCities(),
    this.contactsService.getAllParts()
  );
}
```

All results will be available in a single array with 3 items.

Comment: What happens if one or more service calls fails?

Comment: @AnuradhaGunasekara `forkJoin` won't emit anything.

Answer (score 1):

The `Resolve` interface is defined as follows:

```
interface Resolve<T> {
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<T> | Promise<T> | T
}
```

The method `resolve` can return `Observable`, `Promise`, or just an object of some type. In your case, you should subscribe to contacts, cities, and parts inside the `ContactService`. When all three pieces of data are received there, combine them in an object and return in a separate method,e.g. `getCombinedData`, which you can call from the resolver.

The other option would be to use the RxJS `forkJoin` as it was suggested by martin, but if you'd like to prepare a structured object with combined results, do it manually.